# How to hide a label element with no class?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Trying to hide an element in the WooCommerce plugin for Wordpress. Basically it's on the check out page and it says "State" and I want to hide it because the drop down box already says "Select State." I open Firebug and saw that the text "State" is not part of a class or anything. It looks like this:

```
<label class="" for="billing_state">
State
<abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr>
</label>
```

I tried adding this in my CSS but it didn't work

```
label [for="billing_state"]{
display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be a space between the `label` and the `[`; otherwise you're searching for elements which are *descendants* of a `label`, which match `[for="billing_state"]`.

```
label[for="billing_state"]{
    display: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/J3BgS/

Comment: What browser are you using? Does it work for you in the demo I linked to?

Answer (score 2):

Your CSS works just remove the space between `label` and the `[selector]`:

```
label[for="billing_state"]{
  display: none;
}
```

The demo **http://jsfiddle.net/6hKPL/**

Answer (score 0):

You can select a node with an empty *class* attribute `<span class="" />` using

```
span[class=""] {
    border: 3px solid red;
}
```

You can select a node with explicitly no *class* attribute `<span />` using

```
span:not([class]) {
    border: 3px solid blue;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/GAHRE/)